# Why is the $p-$multiplicator of a $p-$group is an elementary abelian $p -$group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-groups, computational-algebra

Let $G$ be a $p-$group that have the finite presentation $F/R$($F$ is a free group of rank $d$); The $p-$multiplicator of $G$ is defined by
$$
G^* = R/[F,R]R^p
$$
Why $G^*$ in an elementary abelian $p -$group?

Many thanks.

Comment: This is directly from the way it is defined. You have $[R,R]\subseteq [F,R]$ so it is abelian, and you have included $R^p$ so it has exponent $p$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thank you very much for your answer.